# Make Bison accept an alternative EOF token

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm writing an ansi-C parser in C++ with flex and bison; it's pretty complex.

The issue I'm having is a compilation error. The error is below, it's because `yy_terminate` returns `YY_NULL` which is defined as (an int) `0` and `yylex` has the return type of `yy::AnsiCParser::symbol_type`. `yy_terminate();` is the automatic action for the `<<EOF>>` token in scanners generated by flex. Obviously this causes a type issue.

My scanner doesn't produce any special token for the EOF, because EOF has no purpose in a C grammar. I could create a token-rule for the `<<EOF>>` but if I ignore it then the scanner hangs in an infinite loop in `yylex` on the `YY_STATE_EOF(INITIAL)` case.

The compilation error,

```
ansi-c.yy.cc: In function ‘yy::AnsiCParser::symbol_type yylex(AnsiCDriver&)’:
ansi-c.yy.cc:145:17: error: could not convert ‘0’ from ‘int’ to ‘yy::AnsiCParser::symbol_type {aka yy::AnsiCParser::basic_symbol<yy::AnsiCParser::by_type>}’
ansi-c.yy.cc:938:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘YY_NULL’
ansi-c.yy.cc:1583:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘yyterminate’
```

Also, Bison generates this rule for my start-rule (translation_unit) and the EOF ($end).

```
$accept: translation_unit $end
```

So `yylex` has to return something for the EOF or the parser will never stop waiting for input, but my grammar cannot support an EOF token. Is there a way to make Bison recognize something other then `0` for the `$end` condition without modifying my grammar?

Alternatively, is there simply something I can return from the `<<EOF>>` token in the scanner to satisfy the Bison `$end` condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would not include an explicit EOF rule in a lexical analyzer, not because it serves no purpose, but rather because the default is precisely what you want to do. (The purpose it serves is to indicate that the input is complete; otherwise, the parser would accept the valid prefix of certain invalid programs.)

Unfortunately, the C++ interfaces can defeat the simple convenience of the default EOF action, which is to return 0 (or NULL). I assume from your problem description that you have asked bison to generate a parser using [complete symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Complete-Symbols.html). In that case, you cannot simply return a 0 from `yylex` since the parser is expecting a complete symbol, which is a more complex type than `int` (Although the token which reports EOF does not normally have a semantic value, it does have a location, if you are using locaitons.) For other token types, bison will have automatically generated a function which makes an token, named something like `make_FOO_TOKEN`, which you will call in your scanner action for a `FOO_TOKEN`.

While the C bison parser does automatically define the end of file token (called `END`), it appears that the C++ interface does not. So you need to manually define it in your `%token` declaration in your bison input file:

```
%token END 0 "end of file"
```

(That defines the token type `END` with an integer value of 0 and the human readable label "end of file". The value 0 is obligatory.)

Once you've done that, you can add an explicit EOF rule in your flex input file:

```
<<EOF>> return make_END();
```

If you are using locations, you'll have to give `make_END` a location argument as well.

Comment: Thank you! I tried several variations of defining a `%token END` but I never tried defining it as `%token END 0`. Presumable the 0 is just the token's position in the token-table, where `$end` is at index 0, is that correct?

Comment: @matutter: effectively, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to prevent the compiler error `could not convert 0 from int to ...symbol_type` - place this redefinition of the `yyterminate` macro just below where you redefine `YY_DECL`

```cpp
// change curLocation to the name of the location object used in yylex
// qualify symbol_type with the bison namespace used
#define yyterminate() return symbol_type(YY_NULL, curLocation)
```

The compiler error shows up when bison locations are enabled, e.g. with `%define locations` - this makes bison add a `location` parameter to its `symbol_type` constructors so  the constructor without locations

```cpp
symbol_type(int tok)
```

turns into this with locations

```cpp
symbol_type(int tok, location_type l)
```

rendering it no longer possible to convert an `int` to a `symbol_type` which is what the default definition of `yyterminate` in flex is able to do when bison locations are not enabled

```cpp
#define yyterminate() return YY_NULL
```

With this workaround there's no need to handle `EOF` in flex if you don't need to - there's no need for a superfluous `END` token in bison if you don't need it